# risks of signing application assemblies

Tags: c#, gac, strongname, assembly-signing

We consider to put one of our assemblies in the GAC for the purpose of versioning.
This means this assembly must be signed and each other assembly it uses (e.g. 3rd party) must also be signed. Only the 3rd party vendor can do the signature. Is there a practical risk that some vendors will not supply a signed version and we are limitting ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The risk is not applicable.

You can only put an assembly in the GAC if it depends only on other GAC assemblies.
So your 3rd party libs should already be in the GAC.

If they are not, you can fake it (see @Preet Sangha) but then you become the publisher of those libs. And sharing those binaries with other apps will (can) not happen.

Comment: My GAC assembly loads via reflection other assembly on disk (assume this is a requirement since the location is dynamic etc)

Comment: Then maybe it is not so well suited for the GAC.

Comment: my partners will write apps that use this assembly. I don't want them to localcopy=true it, I want to have the freedom to change its routing logic (e.g. new version in gac).

Comment: Did you check if dynamically loaded assy's have to be signed too?

Comment: If you call each method of them in reflection then no, they do not need to be signed. But this is a hard developer model. Anyway I'll do a re thinking on the architecture

Answer (score 1):

You can always sign a third party one with ilmerge.

there's a link on my blog here: http://preetsangha.blogspot.com/2007/10/signing-third-party-assembly.html

Comment: I want my application components to be portable so they can be used in other apps that do not ILMerge but rather ship the binaries as is. Say I have assembly X that depends on Y,Z. If I ILMerge Y,Z to W, is X forced to always require W or will it work if W is not there and Y,Z are?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a risk, but 3rd Party vendors should be signed if they are appropriate for the GAC. You should be able to ask for them to be signed if they are not.

IMO, it is a risk, but not a major one, especially if you have an existing solution that you can verify is all signed.